# React Native : 'undefined is not a function' while using navigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to make an app with 2 panels, one with my user inputs, and the other one with the output (it's all dates, not important).
I am using navigator. My 'main' class is :

```
export default class App extends Component {
onDateChange = (state) => (event,value) => {
    this.setState({
        [state]:value
    });
}

render () {
    return (
        <Navigator
            initialRoute={{id: 'mainPage', name: 'main'}}
            renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
            configureScene={(route) => {
                if (route.sceneConfig) {
                    return route.sceneConfig
                }
            return Navigator.SceneConfigs.VerticalDownSwipeJump;
        }}/>
    );
}

renderScene ( route, navigator ) {
    var routeId = route.id;
    if (routeId === 'mainPage') {
        return (
            <mainPage
                navigator={navigator}/>
        );
    }
    if (routeId === 'calcPage') {
        return (
            <calcPage
                navigator={navigator}/>
        );
    }
}
}
```

And the first page it loads looks like :

```
class mainPage extends Component {
componentWillMount () {
    var navigator = this.props.navigator;
}

constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        dayMes: "",
        monthMes: "",
        yearMes: "",
        dayLast: "",
        monthLast: "",
        yearLast: "",
        dayInit: "",
        monthInit: "",
        yearInit: "",
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <ScrollView>
        <View style={{
            justifyContent: 'center',
        }}>
            <View style={{
                    height: 40,
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    borderTopWidth: 25,
                    backgroundColor: 'white'
            }}/>

            </View>

 LOTS of textInputs ...

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => { navigator.replace({ id: 'calcPage' }); } }>
                <View style={styles.button}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Calculer</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        </ScrollView>
    )
}
}
```

When i press the button though, it gives me an error `undefined is not a function (evaluating 'navigator.replace({id: 'calcPage'})')`. I guess the problem is with the function it triggers, but i don't know where. The calcPage class is the same as the first one, since i'm still testing.

Thanks for the help !

EDIT :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'react-native-datepicker';
import { AppRegistry, View, Image, Text, TextInput, StyleSheet, Alert, Button, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView, Navigator } from 'react-native';
```

my imports

Comment: where did you defined `Navigator`? Not able to see you have imported from any component

Comment: just added my imports in my question :)